# Code blocks wrap on mobile sites

Tags: bug, mobile-web, code-formatting, mobile-firefox

For some reason, code blocks wrap lines on mobile sites. Seen on Android 6.0.1, both Firefox and Chrome:

[image] [image]

Comment: Can't figure anything from the screenshot, please take something in normal size.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The screenshots are normal size (1080x1920), I used the small thumbnails from imgur by adding `s` to image hash.

Comment: @ShadowWizard screenshots now link to the full size images.

Comment: Well, don't think it's a bug, since on mobile it's harder to scroll. More likely a feature of the mobile theme to make the site more easy to access. If you want scrollbars, simply click "full site" in the footer and you'll have them all back.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the code blocks have vertical scroll bars (those are more annoying, rather). They lack horizontal scrolling. If one, why not the other?

Comment: Well, I see no scroll bars in your screenshots... and anyway it's probably easier and more intuitive to have vertical scrollbar.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the code blocks in question aren't long enough for vertical scrolling to be needed. It is easier? So that you can start scrolling on a question and then get trapped in scrolling a code block?

Comment: Just saying that most likely SE dev will mark this bug report as [tag:status-bydesign] at some point. Of course I might be wrong, just using my experience here and sharing my opinion. I'm not against the idea itself and didn't downvote.

Comment: Small correction: Latest Android is **6.0.1**, not 6.1, though I don't think it affects the issue. This is more likely a CSS + browser interaction issue.

Comment: @AndrewT. Corrected, thanks!